# How can I use “Save For Web” in a Batch Action and save new files in their original files folder using Photoshop CS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, batch-processing

Let me explain the title a little further. What I have is a series of PDF files in a series of folders --

Parent Folder
  -Child Folder
     --PDF file
     --PDF file
  -Child Folder
     --PDF file
     --PDF file

What I want to do is open each of those PDFs in Photoshop, and then Save For Web as a jpeg with a series of options (i.e. Blur: 0.192, Quality: 35, etc).
I've already created an action that opens a file as PDF generic with a specific resolution and height, and then an export action of Using: Save For Web, Operation: Save, etc.

Unfortunately, to complete the creation of the Action, I needed to save the file, and the "Export" action now has a path ("In: T:..."). What I want to do is run that Action I created; when doing so it processes all the PDFs and creates JPEGs just fine, but all the files are saving to the same folder that I saved the file to when I created the action. This is a problem as there are non-unique filenames here and there, and what I need is for each of these files to save to the subfolders in which their PDF counterpart lives.

Was I wrong in choosing to do the "Export" in the action? Any help or guidance is extremely appreciated.

NOTE: I am using Photoshop CS 1, I do not have the option to use any of the more recent versions.

Comment: Welcome! This is good question, but a bit of a gray area: batch processing might be an integral part of a designers workflow, yes, but the question itself is more of a technical than a graphic design matter. I'm not saying straight away it's [off-topic](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq), but some may see this more suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com), which is a Q&A site for *general* hardware & *software* questions. Let the community decide, though, the question will be migrated there if it needs to :-)

Comment: I'm going to allow it. Batch transformations are a common tool.

Comment: After doing more research, the ExportOptionsSaveForWeb feature is unavailable in PS7, so it looks like I will have to find a new route. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to managing files, batch actions are a blunt instrument. It is, at its core, single source and single destination designed to facilitate non-complex transformations. If you require digging through a folder hierarchy and saving to the same locations within that hierarchy, then you need to move over to scripting, which would be Applescript for the Mac and Javascript for Windows or cross-platform functionality. That would be an entirely separate discussion outside of simply providing you a script for you to insert your own transformation code.

Answer (score 0):

PS CS1 or PS 7? I had to look up old reviews to remember the feature set. Bridge, which unfortunately didn't ship until CS2, has a script called "Image Processor" that makes this easy -- it allows you to override the Save location in the Action.

In 7 or CS, I think your best option would be to toggle on the dialog for the save command in your action click the little blank square beside the checkbox), so you can manually provide the save directory using a Paste keyboard shortcut.

Memory is dim, but you may find your Save for Web option you're looking for is available only if you run the action in Image Ready.